# Java: Returning Multiple Values to Main Method In Order To Compute Total

Tags: java

The code is below. The program runs a series of calculations based on data input by the user. My problem is that for the most important thing I'm looking for, total kg CO2 emissions, I continually get an answer of 0.0. What I need is a sum of the individual total emissions as calculated in each method, i.e. the values which are printed with the following: System.out.println(trans); System.out.println(elec); and System.out.println(food);

The total should be something like 25040 or whatever, depending on the value of the inputs provided by the user, but I'm constantly getting a total of 0.0., which is obviously false. Could have something to do with the way I've initialized my variables, or something to do with the limitations of returning values from methods. I just don't know what to do. How should I tackle this? All help greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarbonCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double trans = 0;
        double elec = 0;
        double food = 0;

        giveIntro();

        determineTransportationEmission(null);
        determineElecticityEmission(null);
        determineFoodEmission(null);

        calculateTotalEmission(trans, elec, food);

        //printReport(trans, elec, food);
    }

    //Gives a brief introduction to the user.
    public static void giveIntro() {
        System.out.println("This program will estimate your carbon footprint");
        System.out.println("(in metric tons per year) by asking you");
        System.out.println("to input relevant household data.");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    //Determines the user's transportation-related carbon emissions.
    public static double determineTransportationEmission(Scanner input) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("We will first begin with your transportation-related carbon expenditures...");
        System.out.print("How many kilometres do you drive per day? ");
        double kmPerDay = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is your car's fuel efficiency (in km/litre)? ");
        double fuelEfficiency = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("We now know that the numeber of litres you use per year is...");
        double litresUsedPerYear = 365.00 * (kmPerDay / fuelEfficiency);
        System.out.println(litresUsedPerYear);
        System.out.println("...and the kg of transportation-related CO2 you emit must be...");

        //Final calculation of transportation-related kgCO2 emissions.
        double trans = 2.3 * litresUsedPerYear;
        System.out.println(trans);
        System.out.println("");
        return trans;
    }

    //Determines the user's electricity-related carbon emissions.
    public static double determineElecticityEmission(Scanner input) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("We will now move on to your electricity-related carbon expenditures...");
        System.out.print("What is your monthly kilowatt usage (kWh/mo)? ");
        double kWhPerMonth = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("How many people live in your home? ");
        double numPeopleInHome = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The kg of electricity-related CO2 you emit must be...");

        //Final calculation of electricity-related kgCO2 emissions.
        double elec = (kWhPerMonth * 12 * 0.257) / numPeopleInHome;
        System.out.println(elec);
        System.out.println("");
        return elec;
    }

    //Determines the user's food-related carbon emissions.
    public static double determineFoodEmission(Scanner input) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("We will now move on to your food-related carbon expenditures...");
        System.out.print("In a given year, what percentage of your diet is meat? ");
        double meat = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("In a given year, what percentage of your diet is dairy? ");
        double dairy = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("In a given year, what percentage of your diet is fruits and veggies? ");
        double fruitVeg = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("In a given year, what percentage of your diet is carbohydrates? ");
        double carbs = console.nextDouble();

        //Final calculation of food-related kgCO2 emissions.
        System.out.println("The kg of food-related CO2 you emit must be...");
        double food = (meat * 53.1 + dairy * 13.8 + fruitVeg * 7.6 + carbs * 3.1);
        System.out.println(food);
        System.out.println("");
        return food;
    }

    //Calculates total emissions across all sources.
    public static double calculateTotalEmission(double trans, double elec, double food) {
        System.out.println("Your total kg of CO2 emitted across all sources is equal to...");
        double total = trans + elec + food;
        System.out.println((double) total);
        System.out.println("");
        return total;

    }

}
```

Comment: you initialized variables to value zero and are never get populated the right values. you need to store the correct return values i.e trans =  determineTransportationEmission(null);  and for other variables.

Comment: Why do your methods take a parameter that is never used? It looks like you are supposed to create **one** `Scanner` in `main()` and pass it to each method, rather than creating a new `Scanner` in each method.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see... Yeah what I'm doing now seems to cause resource leakage. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: As I said, create **one** `Scanner` in `main()` and then pass it to each method. You should read about how to pass values to a method.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Ah!! Thank you very much Lyju. I did the following and it all worked well.

From this:

```
double trans = 0;
double elec = 0;
double food = 0;
```

To this:

```
double trans = determineTransportationEmission(null);
double elec = determineElecticityEmission(null);
double food = determineFoodEmission(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second problem which popped up here had to do with not correctly passing the Scanner parameter to the multiple methods.

I fixed that by adding the following to the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    double trans = determineTransportationEmission(console);
    double elec = determineElecticityEmission(console);
    double food = determineFoodEmission(console);

    giveIntro();

    calculateTotalEmission(trans, elec, food);
}
```

And because I had three scanner objects, one for each method, I simply removed the Scanners in each and can now pass a single Scanner from my main method to each of the others.